# Scraping <td> values on table generate by Javascript to Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping

I've run with a problem with my web app.
Here's my code:

```
@app.route('/addrec',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def addrec():

   if g.user:
        if request.method == 'POST':

#UPPER PANE

            payor = request.form['payor']


            receiptno = request.form['OR']
            paymentmethod = request.form['paymentmethod']
            naive_dt = time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
            collectiondate = naive_dt = datetime.now() 
            message = request.form['message']
#LOWER PANE
            url_to_scrape = 'http://localhost:5000/form'
            r = requests.get(url_to_scrape)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
            nature = []
            for table_row in soup.select("table.inmatesList tr"):
              cells = table_row.findAll('td')
              if len(cells) > 0:
                nature = cells[0].text.strip()
                natureamt = cells[1].text.strip()
                nature = {'nature': nature, 'nature': natureamt}
                nature_list.append(nature)
            ent = Entry(receiptno, payor,officer, paymentmethod, collectiondate,message, nature_list)
            add_entry(ent)
            actions="Applied"

            return redirect(url_for('form'))

   return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

As you can see I am getting each of the values from my forms and is scraping the values in my table using beautifulsoup. However after I click the submit button, it loads forever. I am getting the valeus from the upper pane but not in the table.

By the way I am generating my cells from a javascript function onClick. Just in case my javascript might be the problem. or maybe there's an easy way to extract these values from the javascrip functions -> python. Here's my javascript code and HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function deleteRow(o){
     var p=o.parentNode.parentNode;
         p.parentNode.removeChild(p);
      }

     function addRow()
      {

        var table = document.getElementById("datatable"),
          newRow = table.insertRow(table.length),
          cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0),
          cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1),
          cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2),


          name = document.getElementById("form").value,
          amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;


          delete1 = delete1 = '<input type="button"  class="btn btn-danger" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"id="delete" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)">';
        cell1.innerHTML = name;
        cell2.innerHTML = amount;
        cell3.innerHTML = delete1;

        findTotal();
      }


 function findTotal(){
   var arr = document.querySelectorAll("#datatable td:nth-child(2)");
   var tot=0;

   for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
      var enter_value   = Number(arr[i].textContent)
      if(enter_value)
                tot += Number(arr[i].textContent);
      }
   document.getElementById('total').value = tot;
 }

</script>
```

HTML:

```
                    <form name="noc">  

                      <input class="form-control input-lg" id="form" list="languages" placeholder="Search" type="text" required>
                      <br>
                      <input class="form-control input-lg" id="amount" list="languages" placeholder="Amount" type="number" required>
                      <br>
                      <button onclick="addRow(); return false;">Add Item</button>
                    </form>




      <table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Nature of Collection</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th></th>

    </tr>
        </thead>
<tbody>
<tr>

        </tr>     
</tbody>

</table>
```

The data of these scraped values, I expect them to be saved to my database. On a cell. If possible I would like the list to be inserted in a column so I can get them later.

Or is there a way I can get the lists on a cleaner and better way to my database? Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Web-scraping a page of your own web app sounds very wrong, just saying.

Comment: @alecxe what would you suggest in this case sir? I also run into the same problem coincidentally

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like you're using requests to try and get data generated by JS. Well this isn't going to work, unless you know some magic a lot of people don't. Requests can't deal with the JS, so it never runs. You should be able to get the data using selenium or something to automate a browser. Otherwise, I don't think you're going to be able to scrape it like this. But if someone knows a way to get JS generated data with requests, please post it.

Comment: I think that's not the case here, the javascript function generates some <td> and I think that's the value he wants to be scraped hoping it could fetch the values he needs. If I were him I would want to find a way to pass those newly created Java script values to my Python script. But yeah, I don't know either, maybe someone knows how to. This is why I'm voting up this question. Someone might know that "magic" imo. Disclaimer: I'm not good with javascript.

Comment: @Rekt Yea that's what I meant. Maybe I need to reword my post, but my understanding is that the JS function won't ever run if you're using requests, so the <td> data doesn't exist in the page you "get". It's given me a headache more than once and I'd love to find a solution that wasn't selenium.